# Is there a quicker way to show/hide multiple columns with Google Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have the script below, I've assigned each one to a button on my spreadsheet so users can either show or hide the columns stated below. My question is - is there a quicker way to achieve the same outcome? This script takes a few seconds so would be good to speed it up.

```
function showColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('National FY21 - 23');
  sheet.showColumns(4,6);   
  sheet.showColumns(12,6);
  sheet.showColumns(20,6);
  sheet.showColumns(28,6);
  sheet.showColumns(36,6);
  sheet.showColumns(44,6);
  sheet.showColumns(52,6);
  sheet.showColumns(60,6); 
  sheet.getRange('B3').setValue('Y');
}

function hideColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('National FY21 - 23');
  sheet.hideColumns(4,6);   
  sheet.hideColumns(12,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(20,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(28,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(36,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(44,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(52,6);
  sheet.hideColumns(60,6); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a quicker way to show/hide multiple columns with Google Appscript?

#### Answer:

*Kind of; you can show all columns in one call but hiding has to be done this way if using the built-in `SpreadsheetApp` Apps Script service.*

#### More Information:

As the columns you wish to hide are separated by columns you do not wish to hide, there is no way of hiding them other than calling each set of columns individually.

You could, however call `sheet.showColumns(4, 62)` to show all columns in the range in one call rather than making calls individually to each subset of columns.

This will only work, however, if there are no columns in-between that are hidden but you do not want to be shown. If this is the case, then unfortunately explicitly calling them individually as you have is the only way to do this.

**Edit:** As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned in a comment on this answer, you *can* make the hide calls in one request too, though to do this you need to activate the Spreadsheet API Advanced Google Service through the `Resources > Advanced Google services...` menu item. This would then utilise a `batchUpdate` request which contains all requests in one API call. It's a little more complicated, but certainly doable.

#### Code:

As I mentioned before you can modify your `showColumns()` function to just show all the columns in one call:

```
function showColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('National FY21 - 23');
  sheet.showColumns(4, 62);
  sheet.getRange('B3').setValue('Y');
}
```

Once the Spreadsheet API Advanced Google Service has been enabled as explained in the 'More Information' section of this answer, you can build a batch request and send it to the API with the following modifications to the `hideColumns()` function:

```
function hideColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('National FY21 - 23')
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  
  var startColumns = [4, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44, 52, 60];
  var requests = []
  
  startColumns.forEach(function(x) {
    requests.push({
      'updateDimensionProperties': {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": 'COLUMNS',
          "startIndex": x - 1,
          "endIndex": x + 5,
        },
        "properties": {
          "hiddenByUser": true,
        },
        "fields": 'hiddenByUser',
      }
    })
  });
  
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests": requests }, ssId)  
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Requests| Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)
- [Requests: `UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest)

Comment: When the batchUpdate method of Sheets API is used, the separated columns can be hidden and shown by one API call. In this case, the process cost is lower than that of Spreadsheet service. Although I'm not sure whether reducing the cost using Sheets API is the OP's direction, I think that when the method using Sheets API is added in your answer, it will be more useful for not only OP, but also other users. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your suggestion. I provided a solution based on `SpreadsheetApp` as this was the service which OP was using, but in this case you are correct, and I have edited my answer to reflect using the Sheets API.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think that your answer will be useful for a lot of users. Thank you, too.